# Unexpectedly lost keyboard - mouse works fine

Tags: keyboard

I was typing in a document a few minutes ago and noticed that the Screen Key popup appeared.  Pretty sure I selected no/cancel.  After this, I lost use of the keyboard (both USB and built in laptop keyboard).

I've since rebooted, but still the same thing.

Beginning to panic.  this is my development system and need it to work.   I cannot SSH in to the laptop because the service is turned off apparently (connection refused).

Any help appreciated.  I cannot find a way to press "return" so I can't install anything.  I'm not seeing a screen keyboard under accessories.

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly enabled long key strokes.  Turned that off in the CP, and am now able to type.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Please never change the title of question if you solved your issue. if you found the solution just post that as an answer. Please note that Ask Ubuntu is a question-answer site and [works very differently from a forum](http://askubuntu.com/about). Thanks